# glClear sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: opengl, c++11

I have very simple openGL code:

screen.cpp

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <iostream>

#define WIDTH 683
#define HEIGHT 384

void init() {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow("test");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if (res != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout<<"Error: "<<glewGetErrorString(res)<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    init();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

The wierd thing is this code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I expect to get a white blank screen, and when I run this program, randomly and more frequently, I would just get transparent screen showing what was there before the program was run. Sometimes the program works correctly and shows me a blank white screen. What is the problem?

compiled with:
g++ -o screen screen.cpp -g -Wall -std=c++11 -lGLEW -lglut -lGL

Answer (score 1):

it's the alpha you specify in clearColor, 0 means transparent, change it to 1 and it will be a proper blank screen.

Comment: The reason why I had it unset was because I didn't set GLUT_ALPHA in glutInitDisplayMode().
I set it as 1 and it still produces inconsistent results.

Comment: That won't make a difference. The value of the alpha component in the clear color only defines the value that gets written to the alpha component in the framebuffer. That doesn't change what gets shown on the screen, it only matters if you use blending. And if you use blending, you typically **do** want to clear the alpha to zero.